# Maximum Sum SubArray

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist

I am trying to find the **contiguous** subarray within an array which has the largest sum. So, for the array

> {5, 15, -30, 10, -5, 40, 10}

the maximum sum possible using those numbers **contiguously** would be 55, or (10 + (-5) + 40 + 10) = 55. The program below outputs the maximum sum of 55, however, the problem I am trying to figure out is how to print the sequence that produces this 55. In other words, how can I print out the 10, -5, 40, and 10?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {5, 15, -30, 10, -5, 40, 10};

    System.out.println(maxSubsequenceSum(arr));         
}

public static int maxSubsequenceSum(int[] X) {
    int max = X[0];
    int sum = X[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < X.length; i++) {
        sum = Math.max(X[i], sum + X[i]);
        max = Math.max(max, sum);
    }
    return max;
}
```

I was thinking of creating an ArrayList to store the `sum` values at every index of i, so the ArrayList would look like (5, 20, -10, 10, 5, 45, 55). And then I was planning on clearing the ArrayList from index 0 to the first negative number in the list, however, this only solves the problem for this specific example, but if I change the original array of numbers, this solution won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track the starting and ending indexes of the current best subarray in your loop. Instead of using `max()` to compute `sum`and `max`, just do the following :

```
int sum_start = 0, sum_end = 0, start = 0, end = 0;
// In the for loop
if (X[i] > sum + X[i]) {
    sum = X[i];
    sum_start = i;
    sum_end = i;
} else {
    ++sum_end;
}
if (sum > max) {
    start = sum_start;
    end = sum_end;
    max = sum;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can replace Math.Max functions by if statements and update start and end index of the best subarray. Pascal version:

```
    if X[i] > sum + X[i] then begin
        sum := X[i];
        start := i;
      end
      else
        sum := sum + X[i];
      if max < sum then begin
        max := sum;
        finish := i;
      end;
```

Comment: Your solution is even better than mine ... I hadnt noticed I could optimize away some useless tracking on the indexes. Well done :)

Answer (score 2):

there is an o(n) solution, a single for loop through the array and reset your sub-sequence whenever your current total is below 0.

{5, 15, -30, 10, -5, 40, 10}

- 5 + 15 = 20
- 20 - 30 = -10 (reset sub-sequence)
- 10 -5 +40 +10 = 55
- end. 55 is max sub-sequence

edit: to get subsequence...
whenever you change max, update your subsequence

- current left index changes only when u reset
- current right index changes every iteration
- new max -> save current left and right index...

Comment: The problem is asking for the subsequence itself, not just its sum.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by capturing the start and end while identifying maximum sub-array as follows:

#### Code

```
package recursion;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MaximumSubArray {

    private static SubArray maxSubArray(int[] values, int low, int high) {
        if (low == high) {
            // base condition
            return new SubArray(low, high, values[low]);
        } else {
            int mid = (int) (low + high) / 2;
            // Check left side
            SubArray leftSubArray = maxSubArray(values, low, mid);
            // Check right side
            SubArray rightSubArray = maxSubArray(values, mid + 1, high);
            // Check from middle
            SubArray crossSubArray = maxCrossSubArray(values, low, mid, high);
            // Compare left, right and middle arrays to find maximum sub-array
            if (leftSubArray.getSum() >= rightSubArray.getSum()
                    && leftSubArray.getSum() >= crossSubArray.getSum()) {
                return leftSubArray;
            } else if (rightSubArray.getSum() >= leftSubArray.getSum()
                    && rightSubArray.getSum() >= crossSubArray.getSum()) {
                return rightSubArray;
            } else {
                return crossSubArray;
            }
        }
    }

    private static SubArray maxCrossSubArray(int[] values, int low, int mid,
            int high) {
        int sum = 0;
        int maxLeft = low;
        int maxRight = high;

        int leftSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = mid; i >= low; i--) {
            sum = sum + values[i];
            if (sum > leftSum) {
                leftSum = sum;
                maxLeft = i;
            }
        }

        sum = 0;
        int rightSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int j = mid + 1; j <= high; j++) {
            sum = sum + values[j];
            if (sum > rightSum) {
                rightSum = sum;
                maxRight = j;
            }
        }
        SubArray max = new SubArray(maxLeft, maxRight, (leftSum + rightSum));
        return max;
    }

    static class SubArray {

        private int start;

        private int end;

        private int sum;

        public SubArray(int start, int end, int sum) {
            super();
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
            this.sum = sum;
        }

        public int getStart() { return start; }

        public void setStart(int start) { this.start = start; }

        public int getEnd() { return end; }

        public void setEnd(int end) { this.end = end; }

        public int getSum() { return sum; }

        public void setSum(int sum) { this.sum = sum; }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "SubArray [start=" + start + ", end=" + end + ", sum=" + sum + "]";
        }
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = { 5, 15, -30, 10, -5, 40, 10 };
        System.out.println("Maximum sub-array for array"
            + Arrays.toString(values) + ": " + maxSubArray(values, 0, 6));
    }

}
```

#### Output

```
Maximum sub-array for array[5, 15, -30, 10, -5, 40, 10]: SubArray [start=3, end=6, sum=55]
```

Solution can be downloaded from  https://github.com/gosaliajigar/Programs/blob/master/src/recursion/MaximumSubArray.java

Answer (score 0):

Two subarray are

[1, 2, 3]

and [4, 9] excluding the negative number

The max sub array here is [ 4, 5]

so the output is  9

Here is the code

```
public class MaxSubArray{
static void sumM(int a[], int n){
    int s1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int k = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int sum = 0;
    int s2 = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

        if(a[i]<s1){
            if(a[i]<0){
                k = Math.min(a[i],s1);
            }
        }

        if(a[i]>k){
            sum+=a[i];
        }

        if(a[i]<k){
            if(a[i]<0){
                continue;
                
            }
            s2+=a[i];
        }

    }
        if(sum>s2){
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(s2);
        }
    
     
}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a[] = {1,2,3,-7,4,5};

        int n = a.length;

        sumM(a,n);
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
 public static int kadane(int[] A) {
        
    int maxSoFar = 0;
 
        
    int maxEndingHere = 0;
 
    // traverse the given array
    for (int i: A) {
         // update the maximum sum of subarray "ending" at index `i` (by adding the
         // current element to maximum sum ending at previous index `i-1`)
         maxEndingHere = maxEndingHere + i;
 
         // if the maximum sum is negative, set it to 0 (which represents
         // an empty subarray)
         maxEndingHere = Integer.max(maxEndingHere, 0);
 
         // update the result if the current subarray sum is found to be greater
         maxSoFar = Integer.max(maxSoFar, maxEndingHere);
     }
 
     return maxSoFar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var maxSequence = function(arr){
  // ...
  if (arr.every((ele) => ele >= 0)) {
    return arr.reduce((sum, ele) => sum + ele, 0);
  } else if (arr.every((ele) => ele < 0)) {
    return 0; 
//for me the maximum would be the biggest negative number 
//arr.reduce((max, elm) => (max > elm ? max : elm))
  } else if (arr === [0]) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    let maxSum = [];
    let currentSum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      currentSum = Math.max(arr[i], currentSum + arr[i]);
      maxSum.push(currentSum);
    }
    return maxSum.reduce((max, elm) => (max > elm ? max : elm));
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

you need to sum all possible sub array. to do that, you can do this code

```
public static int maxSubsequenceSum(int[] X) {
    int max = 0;
    boolean max_init = false;
    int max_from=0;
    int max_to=0; // this is not included
    for (int i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < X.length + 1; j++) {
            int total = 0;
            for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {
                total += X[k];
            }
            if (total > max || !max_init){
                max = total;
                max_init = true;
                max_from = i;
                max_to = j;
           }
        }
    }
    for (int i=max_from;i<max_to;i++)
       System.out.print(X[i]+",");
    System.out.println();
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Surely there's a more efficient solution, though?

Comment: This seems a little inefficient. I am trying to maintain linear time.

Comment: you have to find (N * (N + 1))/2 sum. because you have this amount posible sum. over my solution, some total might be used for next turn as a optimization. but still, you have to have a loop with (N * (N + 1))/2 turn. this is 2 outer loops in my solution

Comment: @Adem Ah, I see. Where in this solution can I print or store the actual sequence of numbers that produces `max`?

Comment: @Adem You don't need to find all (N * (N + 1))/2 sums. See Kadane's algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem (topicstarter posted it's implementation)

Comment: OP has already the best algorithm to find the maximum subarray, he only need something to track the subarray itself along with its sum.

Comment: @MBo , I read the wiki. I did not know the algorithm before. I just write this in 2 minutes.

Comment: @Adem You misread the question. OP has already the best working solution to find the sum, he just needs to get the subarray related to this sum. You proposed a (very) suboptimal solution that doesn't even answer the question. Then you edited to add the "printing" without refactoring to use the aforementioned algorithm :/ .